# count() function in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Avada theme for wordpress, i update the version, but now i'm facing with this issue,  **count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable**, this is the code of the file:

```
    $middle_logo_menu_top_level_elements = 0;
    foreach ( $middle_logo_menu_elements as $menu_element ) {
        if ( null === $menu_element->menu_item_parent ) {
                $menu_element->menu_item_parent = '0';
        }
        if ( '0' === $menu_element->menu_item_parent ) {
                $middle_logo_menu_top_level_elements++;
        }
    }

    if ( $is_search_icon_enabled ) {
        $middle_logo_menu_top_level_elements++;
    }
    if ( $is_cart_icon_enabled ) {
        $middle_logo_menu_top_level_elements++;
    }
    //Here i got the problem
    $top_level_menu_items_count = count( $middle_logo_menu_top_level_elements);
    if ( 0 === $top_level_menu_items_count ) {
         $this->middle_logo_menu_break_point = $middle_logo_menu_top_level_elements / 2;
    } else {...
```

I don't know for what was this code before and don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: @El0din count() is meant for counting the number of elements in an array. Why would you want to count an integer? It's just a value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is obvious if you were to read the manual for the `count()` function. Or the error message you are showing us

Comment: It may be useful if you explain what you are trying to do!

Comment: You updated the theme version or PHP version? If PHP the behavior is documented here, http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php `An E_WARNING will now be emitted when attempting to count() non-countable types (this includes the sizeof() alias function).`

Comment: yes, i updated the php version

Comment: @user3783243 you were the only one who help me, thanks a lot, i finally resolved

Comment: If that's not your code, you should contact the maintainers and alert them to the problem.

Comment: i did, but needed a fast answer

Answer (score 1):

The count function `counts` the number of elements in an array. e.g:

```
$my_array = [ 0, 2, 3, 4 ];

// produces 4
echo count($my_array);
```

What are you trying to do?

Comment: This answer worked better before the question was edited..